# Creating a new record with giving record type

Tags: record-type

I want to create a new record on click of button by giving its record type.

please find the code below

```
public pageReference Test()
    {
       RecordType rt =[SELECT ID, name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'App__c' and name='Test_Contact'];

      this.ap.Client__c = account.Id;
      this.ap.RecordTypeId =rt.Id;
      insert (this.ap);


        pageReference pageRef = new pageReference('/oaoa/TestForm');
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id',ap.id);

       return pageRef;

    }
```

I am getting error as List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Rt is not returning any value

Comment: It seems query made on RecordType is returning null, Did you tried running same query from Console?

Comment: Double check your name.  Is it 'Test Contact' or 'Test_Contact'?  Also, if you simply creating a button that auto-selects the RecordType, it is easier to create a custom URL-button than create a VF page (no test code to write/maintain).   Google "Salesforce URL hacking" for more info, and let me know if you like an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, maybe the query really doesn't return anything?

What does `SELECT ID, name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'App__c'` return?

Is the name really 'Test_Contact'? Look at your config and try with 'Test Contact'. Even better - query by API name of the rec. type (less likely to be translated to French for example ;)):

```
WHERE SObjectType = 'App__c' and DeveloperName = 'Test_Contact'
```