# Assigning name to Recordtype in Accounts

Tags: unit-test

In Account for Recordtype Company i have to give two different names for a test class on account trigger?
How to do that ?

```
Account accobj = new Account();
accObj.RecordType.Name = 'SomeName';
```

Comment: How/what are you running here? and are you receiving any specific error message?

Answer (score 3):

you have to query the RecordType using the developer/api name and assign the id of the record type to the records RecordTypeId field..

```
RecordType rt = [Select Id from RecordType where DeveloperName = 'YourRecordTypeName'];
Account accobj = new Account();
accObj.RecordTypeId = rt.Id;
```

there should be some previous answers which can give you more details..

here's one i found : 
[Creating a new record with giving record type](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21966/creating-a-new-record-with-giving-record-type)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Account accobj = new Account();
 accObj.RecordTypeId = 'Id of SomeName';
```